# Absolute positioning of an element when its parent element is not positioned

Tags: html, css, flexbox

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        ...
    </head>

    <body>
        <head>
            <h1>Donald Duck 3D Expansion Card</h1>
        </head>

        <main>
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="bg">
                        <img src="images/Background.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="role">
                        <img src="images/Donald_Duck.png" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    border: 1px solid gold;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.card {
    width: 528px;
    height: 792px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
}

.bg {
    width: 528px;
    height: 792px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transition: 1s;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.bg img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.role {
    width: 326px;
    height: 460px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    transition: 1s;
}

.role img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.card:hover .bg {
    transform: rotateX(30deg) skewX(-20deg);
}

.card:hover .role {
    transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

Correct position of Donald Duck, with `.card { position: relative}` set:
[Donald Duck 3D Expansion Card (hovered, right positioning)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP2t5.gif)

Wrong position of Donald Duck, without `.card { position: relative}` property:
[Donald Duck 3D Expansion Card (hovered, wrong postioning)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxj4U.gif)

---

The job is to create a 3D expansion effect card triggered when mouse hovers over it, and the Donald Duck should be positioned at the bottom-right corner of the card.

**I wonder what is `.role {position: absolute}` positioned relative to  when `.card { position: relative}` is absent?**

---

At first, I wondered Why it is needed to set `.card {position: relative}` property before using absolute position for the Donald Duck image: `.role {position: absolute;}`.

I found the answer here: [position - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), which basically is that you need to make the parent element `card` box positioned by setting property `.card { position: relative}` to make `.role {position: absolute}` be positioned relative to it.

But when `.card { position: relative}` property is absent, the `role` box seems to be positioned to nothing on vertical dimension.

As shown in the second gif, Donald Duck is positioned to the right side of `wrap` box, and bottom side of nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#containing-block-details)

> If the element has 'position: absolute', the containing block is established by the nearest ancestor with a 'position' of 'absolute',
> 'relative' or 'fixed', in the following way:
>
> - In the case that the ancestor is an inline element, the containing block is the bounding box around the padding boxes of the first and the last inline boxes generated for that element. In CSS 2.2, if the inline element is split across multiple lines, the containing block is undefined.
> - Otherwise, the containing block is formed by the padding edge of the ancestor.
>
> **If there is no such ancestor**, the containing block is **the initial containing block.**

Then

> The containing block in which the root element lives is a rectangle called the **initial containing block**. For continuous media, **it has the dimensions of the viewport and is anchored at the canvas origin; it is the page area for paged media**.

Comment: That helps! I found that the Donald Duck is positioned bottom-right to the initial containing box. And the second I dragged the page to the top, I found the Donald Duck got positioned exactly to the bottom-right of the viewport.